# Bootstrap-Datepicker icon click event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I have the following template containing a calendar icon in a javascript file. It doesn't appear in my html file because it's used dynamically.

```
var iconTemplate = '<li id=\"{streamID}\" class=\"list\">{streamName} <i class="fa fa-calendar pull-right"></i></li>';
```

I want to add a click event to the calendar icon and open date picker. I tried the following:

```
    $('.fa-calendar').click(function(){
      $(this).datepicker();
    });
```

I'm guessing that this doesn't work because it's not calling on a class from the html file. Is it possible to do this all within a javascript file?

Comment: From what I see, you probably need to delegate the event handler. Can you post the html where you inject `iconTemplate` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click, '.fa-calendar', function(){
    ...
```